# Calling a class array inside of a class array C++

Tags: c++, arrays, class

so I have a school project where I'm trying to create a bank account. So I have an array of class customer containing the customer name etc, this customer can have multiple accounts, so I have created an array of class accounts inside of customer. My problem is, I can't call a getter function inside of the account array, I have tried using customerArray[curr_id]->accountArray[curr_acc_num]->get_balance() however I am getting an error telling my that it is unaccessable.

Here is the code, any input would be apprechiated as it is still a work in progress.

```
#include <iostream>.
#include <windows.h>
#include "account.h"
#include "customer.h" 
using namespace std;

bool quit;
int amount;
double bal;
bool valid_pin;
customer* customerArray[200];
account* accountArray[5];
int curr_id;
int curr_acc_num;

//1st name, 2nd name, ID
customer  cust1("Paul", "Smith", 2233);

//ID, Deposit, Pin  
account Paul(112, 222, 6716);

//Welcome screen function
void welcome_screen() {
    cout << endl << endl << endl;
    cout << "\tAbertay Banking" << endl;
    cout << "\t    System " << endl << endl << endl;
    Sleep(1800);
}

//Display account balance function
void account_balance() {
    system("cls"); 
    cout << endl << endl;
    cout << "\tBank of Abertay" << endl << endl;
    cout << "       " << customerArray[curr_id]->get_name() << endl;
    cout << "       ID: " << customerArray[curr_id]->get_custid() << endl << endl;
    cout << "       Balance: " << char(156) << customerArray[curr_id]->accountArray[curr_acc_num]->get_balance() << endl;


    //Display any outstanding loans
    if (Paul.get_loan() > 0) {
        cout << endl << endl;
        cout << "   Outstanding loan: -" << char(156) << Paul.get_loan();
        Sleep(3000);
    }
    //User has no loan on this account
    else {
        Sleep(3000);
    }
}

//Withdrawl function
void withdrawl() {
    bal = Paul.get_balance();
    system("cls");
    cout << endl << endl;
    cout << "\tBank of Abertay" << endl << endl;
    cout << "Enter the amount you wish to withdraw: ";
    cin >> amount;

    //customer has sufficent funds, withdrawl accepted
    if (amount <= bal + Paul.get_overdraft()) {
        bal -= amount;
        Paul.set_balance(bal);
        system("cls");
        cout << endl << endl;
        cout << "\tBank of Abertay" << endl << endl;        cout << "You have withdrawn: " << char(156) << amount << endl;
        cout << "You now have a balance off: " << char(156) << bal << endl;
        cout << "Do you wish to carry out another transaction?"; //do you wish to carry out another transaction.
        Sleep(2000);
    }

    //customer doesn't have enough funds to carry out withdrawl
    else {
        char choice;
        system("cls");
        cout << endl << endl;
        cout << "\tBank of Abertay" << endl << endl;
        cout << "You have insufficient funds in your account" << endl;
    }
}

//Deposit function
void deposit() {
    //balance from user account
    bal = Paul.get_balance();
    char check;
    double ln;
    system("cls");
    cout << endl << endl;
    cout << "\tBank of Abertay" << endl << endl;
    cout << "Enter the amount you wish to deposit: ";
    cin >> amount;

    //Option to  pay off loan, if applicable
    if (Paul.get_loan() > 0) {
        system("cls");
        cout << endl << endl;
        cout << "\tBank of Abertay" << endl << endl;
        cout << "Do you want to pay off your loan? (Y/N)" << endl;
        cin >> check;
        system("cls");
        cout << "\tBank of Abertay" << endl << endl;


        //User selected to pay off loan
        if (check == 'y') {
            //deposit paid into loan
            if (amount < Paul.get_loan()) {
                ln = Paul.get_loan() - amount;
                Paul.set_loan(ln);
                cout << "Your loan is now at: -" << char(156) << Paul.get_loan() << endl;
            }
            //loan is payed of, any extra money is deposited into balance
            else {
                ln = amount - Paul.get_loan() + Paul.get_balance();
                Paul.set_loan(0);
                Paul.set_balance(ln);
                cout << "You have payed your loan off!" << endl;
            }
        }
    }
    //user has no loan or doesn't wish to pay off loan
    else {
        bal += amount;
        Paul.set_balance(bal);
    }
    cout << "You have deposited: " << char(156) << amount << endl;
    cout << "You now have a balance off: " << char(156) << bal << endl;
    cout << "Would you like to select another option with this account?"; //do you wish to carry out another transaction.
    Sleep(1500);
}

//Apply for overdraft
void overdraft() {
    system("cls");
    char choice;
    cout << endl << endl;
    cout << "\tTake out an overdraft of " << char(156) << "300? " << endl;
    cout << "\t            (Y/N)" << endl;
    cin >> choice;
    if (choice == 'y') {
        Paul.set_overdraft(300);
    }
}

//Calculating interest rates
double interest_rate(int loan) {
    //Up to £3,000 rate of 11%
    if (loan < 3000) {
        return 1.11;
    }
    //From £3,000 to £7,000 rate of 9%
    else if (loan > 3000 && loan < 7000) {
        return 1.09;
    }
    //From £7,000 to £21,000 rate of 7%
    else if (loan > 7000 && loan < 21000) {
        return 1.07;
    }
    //From £21,000 over rate of 5%
    else if (loan < 21) {
        return 1.05;
    }
}

//Loan eligibility funcition
void loan_elgibility() {
    double max_loan;
    double loan;

    //Calculating loan eligibility
    system("cls");
    cout << endl << endl;
    cout << "\tBank of Abertay" << endl << endl;
    cout << "Caculating loan eligibility";
    max_loan = (2 * Paul.get_balance());
    Sleep(800);

    //Loan and rates
    system("cls");
    cout << endl << endl;
    cout << "\tBank of Abertay" << endl << endl;
    cout << "    You are eligible to borrow up to: " << char(156) << max_loan << endl << endl;
    cout << "    Interest rates are as follows" << endl << endl; 
    cout << "             -  " << char(156) << "3,000  at 11%" << endl;
    cout << "    " << char(156) << "3,000   -  " << char(156) << "7,000  at  9%" << endl;
    cout << "    " << char(156) << "7,000   -  " << char(156) << "21,000 at  7%" << endl;
    cout << "    " << char(156) << "21,000  -          at  5%" << endl;
    Sleep(6200);

    //User input loan request
    system("cls");
    cout << endl << endl;
    cout << "           Bank of Abertay" << endl << endl;
    cout << "    Enter loan request: " << char(156);
    cin >> loan;

    //Processing loan request
    system("cls");
    cout << endl << endl;
    cout << "           Bank of Abertay" << endl << endl;
    cout << "     We are processing your request..." << endl;
    Sleep(800);
    system("cls");

    //Loan has been approved, loan deposited into account
    if (loan <= Paul.get_balance()) {
        cout << endl << endl;
        cout << "           Bank of Abertay" << endl << endl;
        cout << "Your loan has been approved" << endl;
        bal = Paul.get_balance() + loan;
        loan = interest_rate(loan) * loan;
        Paul.set_balance(bal);
        Paul.set_loan(loan);
        Sleep(800);
    }

    //Loan has not been approved
    else {
        cout << endl << endl;
        cout << "           Bank of Abertay" << endl << endl;
        cout << "You do not qualify for a loan of this amount";
        Sleep(800);
    }
}

//Quit function
void quit_screen() {
    system("cls");
    char choice;
    cout << endl << endl;
    cout << "           Bank of Abertay" << endl << endl;
    cout << "    Do you want to quit? (Y/N) " << endl;
    cout << "         ";
    cin >> choice;


    // customer wants to quit, end while loop and program
    if (choice == 'y') {
        system("cls"); //clear screen
        cout << endl << endl << endl;
        cout << "     Thanks for using," << endl;
        cout << "       Bank of Abertay!"<< endl;
        Sleep(2000);
        quit = true;
    }
    else {
        quit = false;
    }
}

//Request user pin number
bool pin_request() {
    double pin;
    int counter = 0;
    do {
        system("cls");
        cout << endl << endl;
        cout << "\tBank of Abertay" << endl << endl;
        cout << "\tEnter pin: ";
        cin >> pin;
        if (pin == Paul.get_pin()) {
            return true;
        }
        else if (counter == 3) {
            cout << "You have entered an invalid pin too many times!";
            Sleep(800);
            return false;
        }
        else {
            system("cls");
            cout << endl << endl;
            cout << "           Bank of Abertay" << endl << endl;
            cout << "You have entered an invalid pin" << endl;
            Sleep(800);
            valid_pin = false;
            counter++;
        }
    } while (valid_pin == false && counter < 3);
}

//Adding a new customer
int counter = 0;
void add_customer(string first_nom, string second_nom, int cust_ID) {
    customer* new_customer = new customer(first_nom, second_nom, cust_ID);
    customerArray[counter] = new_customer;
    counter++;
}


//creating new bank account
void create_account()
{
    int input_custid;
    double input_balance;
    int input_pin;
    string first_nom;
    string second_nom;
    int cust_ID;
    char choice;

    //Request new customer information
    system("cls");
    cout << endl << endl;
    cout << "\tBank of Abertay" << endl << endl;
    cout << "Enter first name: ";
    cin >> first_nom;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Enter surname: ";
    cin >> second_nom;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Customer ID: ";
    cin >> cust_ID;
    //create new customer class array
    add_customer(first_nom, second_nom, cust_ID);

    //creating new account array
    system("cls");
    cout << endl << endl;
    cout << "\tBank of Abertay" << endl << endl;
    cout << "Enter The account No. :";
    cin >> input_custid;
    cout << "Initial deposit in new account: ";
    cin >> input_balance;
    cout << "Create pin: ";
    cin >> input_pin;
    system("cls");
    cout << "       We are processing your request..." << endl;
    Sleep(800);
    cust1.add_account(input_custid, input_balance, input_pin);
    system("cls");
    cout << "Account Created.." << endl;
    cout << "Thank you for joining the Bank of Abertay";
    Sleep(800);
}


//find user account 
bool find_account() {
    int custID;
    int counter;
    bool found_account;
    system("cls");
    cout << endl << endl;
    cout << "       Bank of Abertay" << endl << endl;
    cout << " Enter your customer ID: ";
    cin >> custID;
    cout << " - ";
    cin >> curr_acc_num;

    //not happy about this!!
    for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
        if (customerArray[i]->get_custid() == custID) {
            curr_id = i;
            return true;
        }
        else if (i == 199) {
            return false;
        }

    }
}



    //an option to send money to another account? 
    // need a function that takes user back to option menu if wrong pin enter!


int main() {
    //welcome screen 
    welcome_screen();
    //while loop until player decides to quit
    do {
        int option_choice;
        system("cls");     //clear screen, updating board every time function called
        cout << endl << endl;
        cout << "\tBank of Abertay" << endl << endl;
        cout << "\t     Menu" << endl << endl;
        cout << "\t1. View Balance" << endl;
        cout << "\t2. Withdraw" << endl;
        cout << "\t3. Deposit" << endl;
        cout << "\t4. Loan eligibility" << endl;
        cout << "\t5. New account" << endl;
        cout << "\t6. Overdraft" << endl;
        cout << "\t7. Quit" << endl << endl;
        cout << "\t\tSelect: ";
        cin >> option_choice;

        //ensure option screen only runs through once unless an invalid option is chosen
        int valid_number_check = 0;
        // do {
        switch (option_choice) {

            //Display account balance
        case 1:
            if (find_account() == true && pin_request() == true) {
                account_balance();
                break;
            }
            else {
                cout << "Your request has been denied";
                break;
            }

            //Account withdrawl
        case 2:
            if ( find_account() == true && pin_request() == true) {
                withdrawl();
                break;
            }
            else {
                cout << "Your request has been denied";
                break;
            }
            //Account deposit
        case 3:
            if (find_account() == true && pin_request() == true) {
                deposit();
                break;
            }
            else {
                cout << "Your request has been denied";
                break;
            }
            //Loan eligibility 
        case 4:
            if (find_account() == true && pin_request() == true) {
                loan_elgibility();
                break;
            }
            else {
                cout << "Your request has been denied";
                break;
            }

            //Create new account
        case 5:
            create_account();
            break;

            //Overdraft
        case 6:
            if (find_account() == true && pin_request() == true) {
                overdraft();
                break;
            }
            else {
                cout << "Your request has been denied";
                break;
            }

            //Quit
        case 7:
            quit_screen();
            break;

            //Invalid number entered
        default:
            cout << endl << endl;
            cout << "           Bank of Abertay" << endl << endl;
            cout << "Please enter a valid number";
            Sleep(800);

            break;
        }
    } while (quit == false);
} 
// main
```

Account .h

```
#pragma once
#include <string> 
#include "account.h"
using namespace std; 

class customer
{
private:
    int custid; 
    string name;
    account* accountArray[5];
    int counter = 0;

public: 
    int get_custid();
    customer(string, string, int);
    string get_name();
    void add_account(int, double, int);
    ~customer();

};
```

Account.cpp

```
#include "customer.h" 
#include "account.h"
#include <string> 
using namespace std;


customer::customer(string first_nom, string second_nom, int cust_ID) {

    counter++;
    string first_name = first_nom;
    string sur_name = second_nom;
    //counting the number  of accounts
    counter++;
    //identification of customer array
    //custid = counter + 1000;
    custid = cust_ID;
}

customer::~customer()
{
}

int customer::get_custid() {
    return custid;
}


void customer::add_account(int id, double dep, int pin) {
    account* new_account = new account(id, dep, pin);
    accountArray[counter] = new_account;
    counter++;
}


string customer::get_name() {
    return name;
}
```

customer.h

```
#pragma once
class account
{
private:
    double balance;
    int custid;
    double loan_amount;
    double overdraft;
    int pin;
    int account_number;

public:
    account(int, double, int);
    ~account();

    //getters 
    double get_balance();
    double get_loan();
    double get_pin();
    double get_overdraft();


    //setters
    void set_overdraft(double over);
    void set_balance(double bal);
    void set_loan(double loan);

};
```

customer.cpp

```
#include "account.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;



account::account(int input_custid, double input_balance, int input_pin)
{
    custid = input_custid;
    balance = input_balance;
    pin = input_pin;
    loan_amount = 0;
    overdraft = 0;
}


account::~account()
{
}


double account::get_balance()
{
    return balance;
}

double account::get_loan()
{
    return loan_amount;
}

double account::get_pin()
{
    return pin;
}

double account::get_overdraft()
{
    return overdraft;
}

void account::set_balance(double bal)
{
    balance = bal;
}

void account::set_loan(double loan)
{
    loan_amount = loan;
}

void account::set_overdraft(double over)
{
    overdraft = over; 
}
```

Comment: That's a lot of code for what sounds like a relatively small problem. Strongly recommend constructing a [mcve].  Odds are extremely high you'll see what went wrong and be able to self-answer or delete the question.

Comment: The account is inaccessible because it is private. But just like you have a `get_name() { return name; }` you could have a `get_balance(int i) { return accountArray[i]->get_balance(); }`

Comment: Unrelated sidenotes picked up  while editing the question: A function with a non-`void` return type must return on all paths. A few functions look like they might not. Didn't look too hard at them, so you might have little dodges in them like this one in `find_account`:  `else if (i == 199) {
            return false;
        }`. Lose that `else if` and just `return false;` at the end of the function. If you got to the end without returning early you automatically found nothing. No need for extra testing.

Comment: Thanks a lot Bo Persson that's exactly what I needed to know! I've spent a lot of time trying to figure it out.

Comment: user4581301 I really appreciate that, even when I was writing the find_account function I wasn't happy with the way I had done it, it makes a lot more sense to do it the way you explained, Ill go through my code looking for that. And after re-reading my question I'll definitely condense the code and make it easier to answer next time, thanks!